# Enabling Bluetooth on Windows 7 (HP Pavilion)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, drivers, bluetooth, hp-pavilion

I have an [HP Pavillion g6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Pavilion_%28computer%29#Current_notebook_models) with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. On Windows 7, it says that my laptop doesn't have Bluetooth, so I thought that my PC doesn't support Bluetooth at all.

However, on Ubuntu, I have Bluetooth, and I can connect my phone to my laptop. I guess my Windows 7 is missing some drivers.

How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to provide the bluetooth device a Windows device driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Bluetooth companion driver for the model wireless adapter you have in your notebook, from those listed under network, on the [support and driver page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5171004#N319).

For example: If you have an Atheros wireless card, you need to install the Atheros Bluetooth Driver, and so forth.

Comment: I'll try that now

Answer (score 1):

Asked By accidentally forget the exact brand of laptop and the exact name of the internal notebook bluetooth card.

Nonsense, say for him, that is bluetooth from Broadcom.

To make it easier to find the exact name of the laptop, you can use the service of HP:

[How Do I Find My Model Number or Product Number?](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?tmp_renderType=findModel&cc=us&dlc=&docname=c00033108&lc=en)

Intel Download Center:

Install [Intel Chipset Software Installation Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software%20Products&ProductLine=Chipset%20Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Chipset%20Software%20Installation%20Utility)

HP Broadcom Bluetooth driver:

Run `sp58944.exe` so that it extracts it to a directory but don't install it.
Manually update the driver by pointing it at the directory.

[HP Broadcom Bluetooth driver var 1](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp58501-59000/sp58944.exe)

Broadcom fix, way 2:

Run `sp56715.exe` so that it extracts it to a directory but don't install it.
Manually update the driver by pointing it at the directory.

[HP Broadcom Bluetooth driver var 2](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp56501-57000/sp56715.exe)

WIDCOMM Bluetooth Software for Windows 8 / Windows 7 / Windows Vista or Windows XP:

[Broadcom: Download updated Bluetooth® for Windows® software (Broadcom® Bluetooth stack for Windows)](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php)